# Relationship between rest resources with Spring boot

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm learnig Spring boot Rest but I can't resolve a problem. Can someone help me?
I created the following mapping between the Product and Category entities:

Category Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
 ...
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
private List<Product> products;
//getters setters
}
```

Product Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lancamento")
public class Lancamento {
...
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_pessoa")
private Pessoa pessoa;
//getters setters
}
```

I wait for this result:

```
{
 "name":"Category_1",
  "products":[
     {
       "id":"1",
       "name":"Product_1"
     },
     {
      "id":"2",
       "name":"Product_2"
     },
   ]
}
```

But the real result is:

```
{
 "name":"Category_1"
}
```

What is wrong? Is there some settings that I need to make?
Thanks.

Comment: Just remove @JsonIgnore annotation))

Comment: when I remove @JsonIgnore, I received cyclic dependency error:  ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: 
 org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON document: 
 Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the `@JsonIgnore` annotation. With this annotation you are telling Spring basically to **ignore** the field while serializing/deserializing the object, hence it won't be present in the output.

[See the Docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html)

Comment: when I remove @JsonIgnore, I received cyclic dependency error:  ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: 
 org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON document: 
 Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Answer (score 0):

You have JsonIgnore on  products field of Category

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@JsonIgnore` annotation.

Because of `@JsonIgnore` annotation this list is getting ignored.

See this https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html to understand `@JsonIgnore`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to romove @JsonIgnore and use DTO-objects for serialization. Anyway this is the proper way to create APIs. You can combine and transform all data from entities in your DTOs as you like.

OR

you can put reverse relation (field) it the Product object, like

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
private Category category;
```

and mark with @JsonIgnore that field.

It's up to you, but better way is to use DTOs

Comment: Thanks :) , I solved the problem using 'code'@JsonManagedReference  and @JsonBackReference

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, I found the solution in [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

the solution for this case is to use the Jackson annotations: @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference.

Category:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
...
@JsonManagedReference 
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
private List<Product> products;
//getters setters
}
```

Product

```
@Entity
public class Product {
...

@JsonBackReference
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_product")
private Product product;
//getters setters
}
```

This works like I need.